# Adding method to ActionController::Base in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a comments section to my Rails app using the commontator gem.

I've gone through the steps of implementation, and I have a link to 'Show Comments (0)' appearing on my page.

However, when I click the link, I get an application error saying:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `current_user' for #<Commontator::ThreadsController:0x007f976f39cc78>):
config/initializers/commontator.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It appears this issue can be solved with the solution here:
https://github.com/lml/commontator/issues/72

Basically, I want to add this code to the ActionController:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

So, my question is, how exactly do I add code to ActionController::Base? I do not see the file in my app directory.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked suggests overriding the class in an initializer, so your config/initializers/commontator.rb would be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to ApplicationController. It's the superclass of all your controllers.